# How to use datagraphwindow of arcgis programmatically

Tags: arcgis

I have been trying to plot a map on axmapcontrol and use the same ITable to create a scatterplot graph in IDataGraphwindow2. Unfortunately the graph appears with correct data but no click events on the graph are working. The left click shows a memory error and the right click shows a disabled menu. For left click I think DataGraphTUI.dll is responsible. When we load the IDataGraphWindow2, we don’t initialize this due to which probably it gives an error.

Please find the code below.

```
IDataGraphWindow2 pDGWin;
IDataGraphT dataGraphT = new DataGraphTClass();
IWorkspace shapefileWorkspace = null;
IWorkspaceFactory shapefileWorkspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass();
shapefileWorkspace = shapefileWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile("C:\\abc.shp "), 0);
featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)shapefileWorkspace;

featureLayer.FeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("c:\\abc.shp"));

ITable gobjJoinedTable = (ITable)featureLayer.FeatureClass;

LoadaxMap(); /// a method to load up the axmapcontrol

dataGraphT.UseSelectedSet = true;
dataGraphT.HighlightSelection = true;
dataGraphT.GeneralProperties.Title = "Scatter Graph";
dataGraphT.LegendProperties.Visible = false;
dataGraphT.get_AxisProperties(0).Title = "Y Axis";
dataGraphT.get_AxisProperties(0).Logarithmic = false;
dataGraphT.get_AxisProperties(2).Title = "X Axis";
dataGraphT.get_AxisProperties(2).Logarithmic = false;

ISeriesProperties seriesProps = dataGraphT.AddSeries("scatter_plot");
seriesProps.SourceData = axMap.get_Layer(0) as ITable; // axMap is the map control. Itable direct binding also works here

seriesProps.SetField(0, "abc.shp-fieldname"); // you may add any fieldname
seriesProps.SetField(1, "abc.shp-fieldname");

dataGraphT.Update(null);
dataGraphT.UseSelectedSet = true;
dataGraphT.HighlightSelection = false;
dataGraphT.Update(null);
pDGWin = new DataGraphWindowClass();
pDGWin.DataGraphBase = dataGraphT;
pDGWin.PutPosition(546, 155, 1040, 540);
pDGWin.Show(true);
```

The memory error is 
Access violation at address 0F4E358B in module 'DatagraphTUI.dll'. Read of addess 00000000

Comment: I needed a functionality where I can plot data in a graph. If user selects some data from the graph on mouse down, (s)he can see the same data plotted in the axmapcontrol. Normally this is done nicely by ArcGIS 9 datagraphwindow. But dynamically (I tried C#) you cannot make it work the way I have coded above. So, you can use MS Charts or Devexpress like Charts to do the plot and selection functionality. On selection you can pickup the values and plot it in axMapcontrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem while displaying the graph.
Fixed it by using this line of code:

```
graphWindow.Application = ArcMap.Application
```

All it needs is a reference to the ArcMap Application.